# Ant junit task doesn't recognize currently working directory

Tags: java, ant

I'm running a JUnit task in a sub directory from a parent build file(in the parent directory) and it gives an IO exception whenever it encounters a file/folder in the sub direcory. If I move these files to the parent directory it works fine. How do I overcome this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up putting the files in the parent directory. Nothing else worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following:

1. Try to put the sub-folders exclusively on the build-path
2. Refresh all the folders or restart eclipse
3. Clean build all the project